# Django: can't load template index

Tags: django

i'm following the Django 1.5 tutorial: Writing your first Django app. In part 3, it teaches how to load a template called polls/index.html. It's supposed to show a bulleted-list containing "What's up", when i point to browser at "/polls/", but when I go to browser

```
http://localhost:8000/polls/
```

, the page is just blank.

here's my polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
    )
```

here's my polls/views.py

```
# Create your views here.

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader

from polls.models import Poll

def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
    'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))

def detail(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at poll %s." % poll_id)

def results(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at the results of poll %s." % poll_id)

def vote(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on poll %s." % poll_id)
```

here's my index.html's directory

```
mysite/polls/templates/polls/index.html
```

here's my index.html

```
{% if latest_poll_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for poll in latest_pol_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{poll.id}}">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Anyone have the same problem?

THX!!!

Comment: Did you set `TEMPLATE_DIRS`?

Comment: `latest_poll_list` not `latest_pol_list`

Comment: Thank you all guys!!! BTW, any IDE or some methods can prevent this kind of stupid typing error?

Comment: While you are testing, you can set [`TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#how-invalid-variables-are-handled) to something so you are warned about an incorrect variable name in your template. The [django debug toolbar](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/) can be useful for debugging as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all function-based views are deprecated. Try a class-based view like `django.views.generic.base.TemplateView`.
If you want to use function-based views `django.shortcuts.render` is useful:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'templates/index.html', {'extra_context' : 'hello'})
```

`get_template` returns a `TemplateDoesNotExist` exception because you missed an 'l' in 'poll':

```
{% for poll in latest_pol_list %}
```

I'm not removing the rest of my post because it's good practice for you, hope you will find it useful.

Comment: -1: Function based views are not deprecated. Only function based generic views were deprecated. The OP is following the tutorial. Replacing the suggested view with a `TemplateView` at this stage would probably confuse matters, rather than helping.