# Django:Template index loads the content of index.html

Tags: python, django

I am almost having the same problem as this other user had:
[Django: can't load template index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512095/django-cant-load-template-index)
My problem is that the instead of loading a blank page, my program is loading the content of the index.html instead of the bulleted list.

here's my polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
)
```

here's my polls/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader

from polls.models import Poll

def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))

def detail(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at poll %s." % poll_id)

def results(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at the results of poll %s." % poll_id)

def vote(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on poll %s." % poll_id)
```

here's my index.html's directory

mysite\polls\templates\polls\index.html

here's my index.html

```
{% if latest_poll_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

and this is my output

```
    {% if latest_poll_list %}
        <ul>
        {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
            <li><a href="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No polls are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

the output is supposed to be a print screen of the webpage produced but I am not allowed to post images but it looks just the same.
please help, I have spent hrs trying to find whats wrong

fixed the indentation and also modified views.py to use render_to_response(). here is what the modified views.py looks like now.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from polls.models import Poll

def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,
    })
    return render_to_response('polls/index.html',
                          latest_poll_list,
                          context)

def detail(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at poll %s." % poll_id)

def results(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at the results of poll %s." % poll_id)

def vote(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on poll %s." % poll_id)
```

by the way I am using python 3.3, Django 1.6.1 and the tutorial I am following is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/
the results were the same even after using render_to_response().

Comment: Fix the indentation please, and Try using the [`render_to_response()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) function.

Comment: fixed the indentation and also modified views.py to use render_to_response().

Answer (score 0):

There was a simple fix to the issue I was having. I don't know where I got the bright idea to edit the html document with Microsoft Word and that was creating an extra folder. basically I removed the render_to_response() modification and used notepad to modify the html. simple fix but gave me a lot of heartache.